Query to SQL Server 2008 R2 with nested function call succeeds in SSMS but fails using ODBC
I have a legacy database that is running SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Edition.
Today, I was trying to use sqlacodegen to generate SQLAlchemy classes via the pyodbc package. I was able to connect to the database without a problem, but I ran into an immediate error with the following query generated by SQLAlchemy:
SELECT 
    CAST(com.value AS nvarchar(max))
FROM 
    fn_listextendedproperty('MS_Description',
           'schema', CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)), 'table', CAST(? AS NVARCHAR(max)), NULL, NULL) AS com;

with the following parameters:
[('dbo', 'Accounting')]

The error was as follows:

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'CAST'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL
Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

However, when I substituted in 'dbo' and 'Accounting' in for the prepared statement wildcards, then ran it in SQL Server Management Studio, the query ran fine.
I then tried using sqlcmd and got the exact same error as when I had run the code through Python, demonstrating this is not a SQLAlchemy or pyodbc error:
1> SELECT
2> cast ( com.value as nvarchar(max) )
3> FROM
4> fn_listextendedproperty
5> (
6>   'MS_Description'
7>   , 'schema'
8>   , cast ( 'dbo' as nvarchar(max) )
9>   , 'table'
10>   , cast ( 'Accounting' as nvarchar(max) )
11>   , NULL
12>   , NULL
13> ) as com
14> go


Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Server SERVER, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the 'CAST'.

I even went and substituted { fn convert ('dbo', SQL_LONGVARCHAR) } per some documentation, but this did not help.
I then ran a similar query against a different Azure SQL Server database, both using the online query editor in the portal and SQLAlchemy ODBC connection, and both succeeded.
I also tried all of the different available drivers I had ('SQL Server', 'SQL Server Native Client 10.0', 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server', 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server', 'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server', 'ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server') as well as various permutations of connection string options (only TrustServerCertificate=Yes; was helpful for 'ODBC Driver 18'), and nothing worked. Yet all of the queries I tried executed successfully in SSMS.
The only way I could get the query to run at all over ODBC was to declare and set variables for the two problematic arguments to fn_listextendedproperties:
DECLARE @schemaname NVARCHAR(max)
SET @schemaname = { fn convert ( 'dbo', SQL_LONGVARCHAR ) }

DECLARE @tablename NVARCHAR(max)
SET @tablename = { fn convert ( 'Accounting', SQL_LONGVARCHAR ) }

SELECT
    CONVERT(nvarchar(max), com.value)
FROM
    fn_listextendedproperty ('MS_Description', 
                             'schema', @schemaname,
                             'table', @tablename,
                             NULL, NULL) AS com

What is causing these errors? Does SQL Server 2008 R2 have some sort of bug, or am I not configuring my ODBC connection properly?

What does: select cmptlevel, @@OPTIONS & 256  from sys.sysdatabases  where name = DB_NAME() outputs?

@siggemannen
cmptlevel: 80 ;
(No column name): 256
Your question prompted me to observe that I get the same syntax error in SSMS when I run the query against storedata rather than master.

That's sql server 2000 level, don't think it even supports nvarchar(max), so i'm not surprised it doesn't work, you should up the comp. level if that's possible, or even better, upgrade your sql server version, 2008 is out of support years ago already

Yeah, this is a system I inherited a few months ago. I'd love to upgrade to 2016+, but I don't know how the thick-client software it backs would work with it. (All of it is VERY out of support.) I may prepare a VM or something with a newer version of SQL Server and attempt to load the data into it at night and run a test.

Yeah, sounds dangerous, sql server 2005 had some changes which broke some sql 2000 code, so i wouldn't change it without testing. You should be able to get it working by using NVARCHAR(4000) i think

If you're using Express why haven't you upgraded? 2008 is end of life and there's no reason to not be on a supported version because Express doesn't have a license cost. It might be legacy, but you still need to secure your environment(s).

I think you've convinced me to take on a new project for the weekend

Per @siggemannen's comment, I ran the following:
select cmptlevel, @@OPTIONS & 256 from sys.sysdatabases where name = DB_NAME()

and the output was:



cmptlevel
(No Column Name)




80
256



According to Microsoft's documentation, this indicates a compatibility level with SQL Server 2000.
I ran the following command in master to update the compatibility level with SQL Server 2008 R2:
ALTER DATABASE <dbname>
SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL = 100

After this, I was able to run the queries without a problem.
Further, I discovered that I had inadvertently been running the SSMS queries against the master database, which was already at compatibility level 100. When I ran the queries in SSMS against the DB I was interested in, I got the same errors as I did with ODBC.

Just a little warning, as i wrote it in the comment, the application running on the database might have problems with new compatibility due to some changes made between 2000 and 2008, so you need to test it carefully
